# When someone speaks ambiguously

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Please imagine someone's statements are very ambiguous and vague. How shall one express this matter and indicate that ambiguity in that guy's words:

> - His words were full of **ambiguity**.
> - His words were full of **vagueness**.
> - His words were full of **obscurity**.

I googled various structures, but I didn't find any proper answer to my question unfortunately. I would be thankful if someone could let me know if my sentences are natural and if not, how a native speaker would indicate such a message?

For me they all work. Meanwhile, I need to know if the structure "someone's words were full of..." works here or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences are understandable

> His words were full of ambiguity/vagueness/obscurity.

but it's a little verbose, more simply you could say

> What he said was ambiguous/vague/obscure.
>   He was ambiguous/vague/obscure.

You can only use the last sentence if it's understood that the person was speaking since he might have been ambiguous/vague/obscure in his writing or gesturing.

While there is nothing technically wrong with your sentences, there is a set expression

> **full of shit**

If you were to stop your sentence at an inopportune point, the listener might assume you were going to use this set expression.